# Convert URL Language

Tags: url, dns

This question may be impractical and may be stupid, so please pardon me.

I want to change the **LANGUAGE OF URL**.
For example,

If the URL is 
    www.google.com

I just want to translate it to another Language(HERE 'MALAYALAM- An Southern Indian Language'). In Malayalam "Google" looks like "ഗൂഗിള്‍" . Means I just want to display in my address bar as www.ഗൂഗിള്‍.com instead of  www.google.com.

Simply, how can I create default english URL to alternate language URL. PHP, Javascript, Jquery are preferred.

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP, this is a DNS question

Comment: i dont want a new URl,I mean just an URL converting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical solution to this. The only way to do it is to purchase the actual domain `ഗൂഗിള്‍.com` and to host a web site under it.

That domain name, however, is already taken and points to a Google search form.

See [Wikipedia on Internationalized Domain Names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)

Comment: It seems as the OP is asking for address bar rewriting tho. What's still unpractical when someone copies the url and eventually doesn't land on the place where they were before. Your answer is *technically* correct tho :)

Comment: i dont want a new URl,I mean just an URL converting .

Comment: @Allendar- is it possible with <iframe> ? Do you think?

Comment: @Kiran as said, you can't "convert" a domain name to some arbitrary value if you don't own the name. Do you own `ഗൂഗിള്‍.com`?

Comment: No, i just want to know whether URL Language is convertable or not.

Comment: @Kiran no, you have to own the domain. Otherwise, any web site could pretend being on a domain that it doesn't own. That would make no sense whatsoever.